# Use existing origination entity in a different US region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, aws-pinpoint

I have an existing origination entity in us-east-1 to send SMS messages vis SNS. Now I also would like to send SMS messages from SNS in us-east-2. But I get the following message while adding a new subscription in my us-east-2 topic:

`An error occurred while attempting to add a phone number to the SMS sandbox. The phone number was not added.
Error code: UserError - Error message: No origination entities available to send`

The documentation is not very clear on whether one needs an origination entity for every region or per country. Am I getting the message because I would have to also register an origination entity in us-east-2?

And/or are origination entities not available in us-east-2?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost all AWS resources are on a per-region basis. This includes origination entities. You can either purchase another origination entity in the other region you are using, or send your SNS Publish request to the region where you have the origination entity, and SNS will be able to pick up the region-local resource that way.